# Toggle table cells using pure CSS

Tags: css, toggle

Is there any way to toggle (Show / Hide) table column or row with checkbox using CSS no JavaScript?

I've done the following code it does works with div but not with column or row

```
    <label for="trigger">Toggle box</label>

<input id="trigger" type="checkbox">
<div class="box">
Harry I've got Toggled
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
           <td class="box"> I am a column1, I've got same class but sadly did not get toggled! do you know why?</td>
            <td>  I am a column 2 I don't have any class</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<style>

.box {
  display: none;
}
#trigger:checked + .box {
  display: block;
}
table,
td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

thead,
tfoot {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

How can I toggle table column or row?

Answer (score 1):

your selector is not correct, it should be `#trigger:checked ~table .box`

look first for a following sibling , then for the child of that sibbling if it stands inside.

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
#trigger:checked ~ .box,
#trigger:checked ~table .box {
  display: block;
}
table,
td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

thead,
tfoot {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<label for="trigger">Toggle box</label>

<input id="trigger" type="checkbox">
<div class="box">
Harry I've got Toggled
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
           <td class="box"> I am a column1, I've got same class but sadly did not get toggled! do you know why?</td>
            <td>  I am a column 2 I don't have any class</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you how can I toggle the row / rows that does not got class?